# Module configuration and layout configuration in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I got some codes from other articles for configuring module and layout in zend framework. I tried with in my local. i didn't get different layout for default and admin module. Here is my code for configuring module and layout for zend framework.

***configs/application.ini***

```
[production]

# Debug output
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0

# Include path
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

# Bootstrap
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

admin.bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/admin/Bootstrap.php"
admin.bootstrap.class = "admin_Bootstrap"

# Front Controller
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.env = APPLICATION_ENV

# Session
resources.session.name = "ZendSession"
resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session"
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 86400

# Layout
resources.layout.layout = "layout"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts"
admin.resources.layout.layout = "admin"
admin.resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/admin/layouts"

# Views
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
resources.view.basePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/"
resources.view[] =

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] =
resources.view[] =
admin.resources.view[] = 

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

***application/Bootstrap.php***

```
<?php

/**
* Ensure all communications are managed by sessions.
*/
require_once ('Zend/Session.php');
Zend_Session::start();

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {

     protected function _initDoctype() {
      $this->bootstrap( 'view' );
      $view = $this->getResource( 'view' );
      $view->navigation = array();
      $view->subnavigation = array();
      $view->headTitle( 'Module One' );
      $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/clear.css');
      $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/main.css');
      $view->headScript()->appendFile('/js/jquery.js');
      $view->doctype( 'XHTML1_STRICT' );
      //$view->navigation = $this->buildMenu();
   }

    /*protected function _initAppAutoLoad()
    {
   $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
       'namespace' => 'default',
       'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH
        ));
   return $autoloader;
    }*/

    protected function _initLayoutHelper()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('frontController');
        $layout = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(
            new ModuleLayoutLoader());
    }


   public function _initControllers()
   {
       $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
      $front->addModuleDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/admin/', 'admin');
    }

    protected function _initAutoLoadModuleAdmin() {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'Admin',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/admin'
        ));

        return $autoloader;
    }

    protected function _initModuleutoload() {
      $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader ( array ('namespace' => '', 'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH ) );
      return $autoloader;
   }

}

class ModuleLayoutLoader extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
// looks up layout by module in application.ini
{
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        $bootstrap = $this->getActionController()
                          ->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
        $config = $bootstrap->getOptions();
        echo $module = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
        /*echo "Configs : <pre>";
        print_r($config[$module]);*/
        if (isset($config[$module]['resources']['layout']['layout'])) {
            $layoutScript = $config[$module]['resources']['layout']['layout'];
            $this->getActionController()
            ->getHelper('layout')
            ->setLayout($layoutScript);
        }
    }
}
```

***application/modules/admin/Bootstrap.php***

```
<?php
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
/*protected function _initAppAutoload()
{
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => 'admin',
        'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/admin/'
    ));
    return $autoloader;
}*/
   protected function _initDoctype() {
      $this->bootstrap( 'view' );
      $view = $this->getResource( 'view' );
      $view->navigation = array();
      $view->subnavigation = array();
      $view->headTitle( 'Module One' );
      $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/clear.css');
      $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/main.css');
      $view->headScript()->appendFile('/js/jquery.js');
      $view->doctype( 'XHTML1_STRICT' );
      //$view->navigation = $this->buildMenu();
   }
}
```

Please go through it and let me know any knows how do configure module and layout in right way..

Thanks and regards,

Prasanth P

Comment: I don't understand.. why you guys down voting to this post?. This post is almost hit on google search as well as reviewed by most of people!!..

Comment: If the answers are wrong please down vote to answers only and not for the post. Thanks..

Answer (score 24):

I use plugin approach with this code I have written:

in main Bootstrap:

```
protected function _initPlugins()
{
        // Access plugin
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance(); 
        $front->registerPlugin(new MyApp_Plugin_Module());
}
```

In plugin directory:

```
class MyApp_Plugin_Module extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {

        $module = $request->getModuleName();
        $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();

        // check module and automatically set layout
        $layoutsDir = $layout->getLayoutPath();
        // check if module layout exists else use default
        if(file_exists($layoutsDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $module . ".phtml")) {
            $layout->setLayout($module);
        } else {
            $layout->setLayout("default");
        }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You also need to call `Zend_Layout::startMvc()` in your bootstrap before including this file

Comment: Please not that you can get path to module's directory using `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getModuleDirectory()`

Comment: When i tried this code i was getting Zend_View Exception that "could not find default.html". I had my file name as layout.phtml. When i changed it to default.phtml it worked. Also module specific layouts need to be stored under /application/layouts/scripts with same name as the module. Hope it helps someone who is still wondering how it works. Thank You.

Answer (score 8):

From your code:

```
# Layout
resources.layout.layout = "layout"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts"
admin.resources.layout.layout = "admin"
admin.resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/admin/layouts"
```

you are using your_app/modules/admin/layouts/admin.phtml as admin module layout, and I guess it replaced your_app/layouts/layout.phtml. Check a way to switch between modules and try something site.ressources.layout instead of resources.layout.layout. i am a newbie to zend. check out how to setting up you bootstrap at http://www.survivethedeepend.com/

the same problem and solution has been stressed here: http://blog.astrumfutura.com/archives/415-Self-Contained-Reusable-Zend-Framework-Modules-With-Standardised-Configurators.html

Answer (score 6):

In my application I configured this way. It worked perfectly.

```
protected function _initLayout(){
    $layout = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    if(in_array('admin', $layout)){
        $layout_dir = 'admin';
    }else if(in_array('default', $layout)){
        $layout_dir = 'default';
    }else{
        $layout_dir = 'default';
    }
      $options = array(
             'layout'     => 'layout',
             'layoutPath' => APPLICATION_PATH."/modules/".$layout_dir."/views/layouts"
      );
    Zend_Layout::startMvc($options);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a Controller Plugin to achieve that, because the layout is set based on the request entry, and on the bootstrap the application hasn't been dispatched, so you need to use a controller plugin to work on the preDispatch to switch layouts.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is check the URI_String. Please see below:

I have a module named as "admin".
Under layout folder I have 2 directories. **"site" and "admin"**

\application\layout\site\layout.phtml and \application\layout\admin\layout.phtml

Add this block of code on Bootstrap.php
It just change the layout directory path.

```
protected function _initLayout(){
    $layout = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    if(in_array('admin', $layout)){
        $layout_dir = 'admin';
    }else{
        $layout_dir = 'site';
    }

      $options = array(
             'layout'     => 'layout',
             'layoutPath' => APPLICATION_PATH . "/layouts/scripts/".$layout_dir,
      );

    Zend_Layout::startMvc($options);
}
```

Comment: It will be bad idea if you want to add some user friendly rewrites, e.g. www.mysite.com/user-admin.html

Answer (score 1):

Your questions answered my question, that's right, I was trying to find out why it did not work in my bootstrap modules, seen in its configuration file that you need to add the line

`administrador.resources.view [] =`

Valew partner!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

   public function _initAutoload() {
            $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
            $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(
                    array(
                            'namespace' => '',
                             'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules'

                    )
            );

             return $moduleLoader;
    } 


protected function _initViewhelpers()
{
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();
    $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
    $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
}


protected function _initNavigation()
{
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml','nav');

    $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);
    $view->navigation($navigation);
}

}
```

Comment: Could you offer a little explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Layout and module in not enabled on a newly zend project (**in ZF version 1**). It needs to be enabled and you need to make it work.

Layout works for the common header and footer for the working zend project, on the other hand module can be used for the different kind of access i.e module for user, module for admin, module for visitor and so on.

For a quick reference you can find a complete explanation with a complete project to get the basic idea from here, on my site. . http://www.getallthing.com/how-to-use-layout-and-module-in-zend-framework/

Good luck and cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
$options = array(
         'layout'     => 'layout',
         'layoutPath' => APPLICATION_PATH."/modules/".$layout_dir."/views/layouts"
  );
Zend_Layout::startMvc($options);
```

Tried a few other solutions from SOF and this one worked great. Just needed to point the layoutPath to the folder of the actual layouts