# Zend Franework Layout and Modules

Tags: php, zend-framework, layout, module

I have a some modules and 1 layout. How can i do this thing?:

For each module content of the site should be individual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614742/module-configuration-and-layout-configuration-in-zend-framework). Basically your best bet is to create a controller plugin to choose the right layout depending on request.