# Zend Framework Common Layout and Modules

Tags: php, zend-framework, layout

I have a next structure of my project:

```
/application
   /modules
      /default
         /layouts
         ...
      /news
      ...  
   /configs
   /layouts
      common.phtml
```

Header and footer on all pages are the same. I have a block with changing content for different modules. It is not work now. Can you help me. May be you did this things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614742/module-configuration-and-layout-configuration-in-zend-framework). Everything you need to know to get you started withzend layout and modules.

Answer (score 0):

this will helpful to you. [Matthew Weier O'Phinney's Module Bootstraps in Zend Framework: Do's and Don'ts](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/234-Module-Bootstraps-in-Zend-Framework-Dos-and-Donts.html)